# Is $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\},\; A \mapsto Ae_1$ a closed map?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, closed-map

**Question:** Consider the map from the title
$$f \colon \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\},\qquad A \mapsto A\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

> Is it a closed map, i.e. does it map closed sets $A \subseteq \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ to closed sets $f(A) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$?

**What I've tried**: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps#Properties%20Wikipedia), this is equivalent to the condition that for all subsets $A \subseteq \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, we have
$$
\overline{f(A)} \subseteq f(\overline{A}).
$$

So, for example, if I take the sequence of matrices
$$
a_n =\begin{pmatrix}
2 & n \\ 1/n & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
then we have $f(a_n) \to \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ but $(a_n)_n$ itself does not converge. So maybe one can construct a set $A$ containing the image of this sequence, but its closure does not contain a matrix with first row $\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: You meant $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$, right?

Comment: @Ennar Yes, thanks. I corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are nearly there:
$$A=\left\{\pmatrix{2&b\\c&1}:bc=1\right\}$$
is a closed subset of $SL_2(\Bbb R)$ but $f(A)$ is not
closed, by your example.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if $f$ is an open map instead?

Comment: I have posted this as a new question now here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2780356/88291